# AngularJS watch list exclude

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How do you run a digest loop on manual selected watches? For example I want a directive that displays the current time (with seconds), but I do not want to trigger the digest loop every second. One solution is to update the value outside of angular's digest loop (using jQuery). Other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can restrict (somewhat) the scope of the digest by calling `$scope.$digest` instead of `$scope.$apply`. The former will trigger a digest only on the subtree of your $scope, whereas the latter triggers the digest from the root scope.

Comment: Love it. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to "restrict" the digest effect is to run the digest only on the current scope and its children. This is done with `$scope.$digest()`.

In contrast, `$scope.$apply()` calls the digest from the root scope, so in that sense it is the same as doing `$rootScope.$digest()`.

**EDIT:**

If you are using `$timeout`/`$interval`, then make sure to set the `invokeApply` parameter to `false`, otherwise it will trigger a digest from the root.

Answer (score 1):

Your clock directive will probably use `$timeout` or `$interval`, which have the following signature:

```
$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

Notice the `invokeApply` parameter. If you set it to `false`, angular will **skip** dirty-checking.

Comment: Does not invoking apply means that the DOM object won't be updated?

Comment: A change on the model won't be reflected in the view. You'll have to update the DOM by yourself, yes.

Comment: I actually think there is no magic if you want to avoid triggerring digests: you'll have to do the work outside the angular context. Using `$interval` with *invokeApply* to `false` is just for *consistency*, so as to avoid yourself mixing between `setInterval` and `$interval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use angulars `$interval()` instead of javascripts `setInterval` for your clock.
`$interval` will take care of digest.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

**update:**

I actually have a clock directive in the project I'm currently working on:

Directive:

```
app.directive('clock', ['$interval', 'dateFilter',function($interval, dateFilter) {

return {
  restrict:   'E',
  scope:      {
    format:   '=',
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var format;
    var stopTime;

    // set the time in the directive
    function setTime() {
      element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
    }

    // update the UI on change.
    scope.$watch(attrs.format, function(value) {
      format = value;
      setTime();
    });

    format = attrs.format;
    updateTime();
    stopTime = $interval(setTime, 1000);

    element.on('$destroy', function() {
      $interval.cancel(stopTime);
    });
  }
};

}]);
```

Usage:

```
<clock format="'H:mm'"></clock>
```

Comment: That's not the solution. Using $interval will trigger another digest loop with dirty-checking. I'm looking for a way to avoid this while still using angular's standard API and updating only a small part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your watcher with a debounce utility function.
David Walsh has provided a quite sweet [solution](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).
Here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SQuVy/1295/):

```
angular.module('watchApp', []).controller('watchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.b = Date.now();


    $scope.$watch("b", _debounce(function (b) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.b = Date.now();
            $scope.count += 1;
        })
    }, 1000));
});
```

Comment: This does call `$apply` every second. I think D. Walsh wanted here to avoid triggerring multiple `$apply` in a second.

Comment: I don't really get your point. `$apply` is used just because the isolated scope of the controller is not "aware" that the timeout has ended and the model is not updated. That's just my taste on solution of the problem as I hate injecting built in JS functionality as mutated Angular wrappers, like `$timeout` or `$interval`.